# Need Guidance With Virus Removal (Website)

Tags: wordpress, security, web, virus, webflow

We designed the website in Webflow without copying the code files from WordPress (the website was developed in WordPress).

We created the same design in Webflow, and we want to clear the spam urls from Google search results.

But Google search results are showing new spam URLs after hosting in Webflow. Please guide us on how we can set or remove these spam urls or virus from Google Search.

1. Shifted our website from Wordpress to Webflow.
2. Google Removals Tools
3. Spam Urls used in Sitemap for fixing search result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FPJQ.png)